# Can a company stop paying dividends?

Tags: stocks, dividends

I know that Apple, for example, began paying dividends in 2012. Can a company do the opposite, namely stop paying dividends suddenly?

Comment: Apple also stopped paying dividends in 1995.

Comment: Sure, it happens all the time for various reasons.

Comment: Are you really asking whether you will get some notice that they won't be paying a dividend?

Comment: A bit obvious, but whether or not a company pays out dividends a given year and how much, is decided by the owners - ie. the stock-holders.  It's the stock-holders who vote their shares on such things - or partake in electing the board which does.  Just to point out that this is not something *The Company* just decide by itself, divorced from the share-holders - on the contrary it's the share-holders who decides.

Comment: @BaardKopperud Not really. That's management decision and shareholders can change the management if they don't like it.

Comment: @Joe that would be another good question

Comment: @BaardKopperud Can the board decide to pay out profits to the large shareholders without paying dividends to the rest?

Comment: @JayKeegan Errm the authorities tend not to like that - there are laws to protect small investors in good stock markets

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes. Companies increase, decrease, start paying and stop paying dividends when they think it appropriate.

If a company has been going through some problems and makes a loss, or even a large decrease in profits, they can choose to stop paying dividends until things improve. Many companies did this during the [Global Financial Crisis of 2007-08](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%9308).

Comment: In essence, companies can stop paying dividends whenever they want.  They don't cause who would want to invest in a stock that doesn't "pay out". So on the one hand you have "it's better to keep all our profits" balanced against "it sure would be nice to have more people buying our stocks and raising our capitol".

Comment: @coteyr: "More people buying our stocks" does not mean raising capital. Issuing new stock raises capital, but most people who buy stocks buy them on the open market from other investors. In fact, paying dividend reduces the capital, and it's weird to see a company both raise and reduce capital at the same time. Either a company has more cash than it needs for its plans (pay dividend), or it has more plans than capital (issue new shares)

Comment: I agree, I oversimplified. The point is that when you buy stocks part of the consideration is rather they have a good history of paying dividends. Stocks would not go up in price (desire) if there wasn't a divided driving it at some point. The balance part is just that. I can keep all my profits (reinvest) and pay no dividends, but then why would anyone value my stock?

Comment: @Coteyr, part of the consideration for some people is a dividend payment.  PLENTY of stocks have soared in price without ever paying a dividend.  It is clear you have no idea how any of this works.

Comment: @quid Stocks that don't pay dividends are only valued due to the expectation that they'll start paying one at some future point (either when they're profitable or when they're sooo profitable they don't know what to do with their money).  If a company guarantees it will never pay a dividend, then you're investing according to the 'greater fool theory' --not a wise decision.

Comment: @publicwireless, Sure, at some point an investor will want to see a return on their investment.  Companies have value and that value fluctuates based on a host of factors.  The greater fool theory involves buying an unjustifiably high priced security to sell it at yet a higher unjustifiably high price to an even more foolish person.  There are plenty of unjustifiably high priced dividend paying companies too.  Plenty of companies justifiably rise in value, that rise in value includes some kind of expected future liquidity event which may or may not be a dividend payment.

Comment: What's a non-dividend 'liquidity event'?  Dissolving the company and giving people their money back?

Comment: @publicwireless, yes, liquidating the enterprise would be a liquidity event.  Selling the entire company could be a liquidity event.  There are loads of business where sale to a larger entity is the endgame.  Not everything is dividend based.  Singularly focusing on dividends when valuing an enterprise is foolish and dividend payments are absolutely not the only reason a stock goes up in price.

Comment: @publicwireless - traders, of which there are many different types, don't usually buy and sell stocks for dividends. If dividends was the only reason for investing/trading then there would be no FX or Commodity Markets.

Answer (score 2):

Dividends are supposed to be paid from company profits ([in the current or previous financial years](https://www.gov.uk/running-a-limited-company/taking-money-out-of-a-limited-company)), there are nuances around what profits mean from country to country, but the link is the UK definition from the HMRC. Profits from previous financial years are commonly called retained earnings.

There are a few items around this

- If the company is not currently profitable and has no retained earnings, there will be no dividend
- If the company is currently profitable or has retained earnings, they will usually choose to reinvest a certain proportion of their profits back into the business for development. This is discretionary.
- If the company is currently profitable or has retained earnings, [there can be multiple classes of share (in some countries) that attract different levels of dividend](http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/any-answers/dividends-for-directors-with-different-share-classes), so again you may have a class "B" share that gets no dividend, while the class "A" shares receive a dividend.
- If the company is currently profitable or has retained earnings, then finally, the class of share you have may get a dividend.

Comment: AFAIK, companies may also pay dividends out of *retained earnings* (past profits not paid out), even though current/recent periods may have been ones in which losses were incurred.

Comment: As per @ChrisW.Rea's comment, the first sentence is plain wrong, sorry. Companies are *more likely* to pay dividends if they are profitable, but there are certainly companies that aim to pay a constant stream of dividends whether a particular quarter or year was profitable or not (and therefore retain earnings in good years), as well as [highly profitable companies that pay dividends only very rarely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkshire_Hathaway) or not at all.

Comment: Penn Central kept paying dividends until bankruptcy - they weren't making any profit, obviously.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea ... yes apologies, you are right. I'll amend my answer

Comment: @StephanKolassa. I have corrected my answer in line with the UK HMRC's guidance and Chris' point.

Comment: Thanks, this is better. I have changed my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @MarcusD - as Agent_L has given an example of, some companies don't make enough of a profit and don't have enough retained earnings but actually borrow funds to maintain paying their dividends. That is why investing solely based on dividends can be a dangerous practice.

Comment: At least in US, if they distribute more than current+retained earnings it is technically [**return of capital**](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc404.html) rather than dividend; this changes the timing of taxes, but usually not the amount. And this doesn't alter any effect on the company finances and valuation/stock.

Comment: Wow, scary, UK on the surface is slightly more clear cut ... but then again I'm sure there are nuances with the UK that allow for dividends to be paid out that aren't as the HMRC declare. Of course you could be like some of the large multinationals and not pay any tax on money that is earned in the country, so you could declare dividends from profits in other countries ... that's why accountants are a thriving workforce!

Comment: I upvoted @dave_thompson_085 for mentioning RoC (return of capital). However, "usually not the amount" isn't quite right. A dividend can be qualified or non-qualified (this is all US, don't know about UK or other countries). Having it classified as RoC changes it to a capital gain (when you sell the stock) which can be short-term or long-term. So the amount *can* be the same (a non-qualified dividend reclassified as RoC and the stock sold after a year or less, plus your income and income tax rates not changing), or it can be completely different.