# Can a company announce to give dividends (quarterly) and after two quarters decides not to give dividends?

Tags: stock-markets, dividends, online-trading, stock-dividend

Can a company announce to give dividends quarterly and after two quarters decides to stop giving dividends? Or it is obligated to do for the remaining two quarters?

Comment: There was a similar question in the past [Can a company stop paying dividends?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/64237/86332)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Companies can reduce or suspend dividends at any time prior to the next date of record.This is done in order to preserve cash when capital in difficult market times.

In 2020, many well known companies did so due to Covid (OXY, CCL, WYNN, MAR, F, BA, DAL, BUD, et al).